# How setState works with memo in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am learning React trying to make a task manager app. I am trying to memorize the components with memo, but when doing so the state behaves strangely, when completing a task by clicking on the checkbox of 2 different tasks, other gif attachments are uncompleted so that you understand what I mean:
[image: Image from Gyazo]

I leave a codebox with the complete code:
[image: Edit react-app-manger]

and git repository: https://github.com/FrancoRodao/learning-react/tree/master/src

Task component:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import TaskRow from "../TaskRow";

const initialState = [{"id":1,"title":"1","description":"","done":false},{"id":2,"title":"2","description":"","done":false},{"id":3,"title":"3","description":"","done":true}]

function Tasks(props) {

    const [taskItems, setTaskItems] = useState(initialState)

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!props.newTask) return
        newTask({ id: taskItems.length + 1, ...props.newTask })
    }, [props.newTask])


    const newTask = (task) => {
        updateItems([...taskItems, task].map((task) => ({ ...task })))
    }

    const toggleDoneTask = (id) => {
        let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }))
        let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
            if (t.id === id) {
                t.done = !t.done
            };
            return t;
        })
        updateItems(newItems)
    }

    const updateItems = (tasks) => {
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(tasks))
        setTaskItems(tasks)
    }

    return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <h1>learning react </h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Title</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Done</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {

                        props.show ? taskItems.map((task, i) =>
                            <TaskRow
                                task={task}
                                key={task.id}
                                toggleDoneTask={toggleDoneTask}>
                            </TaskRow>)
                            :

                            taskItems.filter((task) => !task.done)
                                .map((task) =>
                                    <TaskRow
                                        show={props.show}
                                        task={task}
                                        key={task.id}
                                        toggleDoneTask={toggleDoneTask}></TaskRow>
                                )
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </React.Fragment>
    )
}


export default Tasks
```

Task Row (task item) component

```
import React, { memo } from 'react'
import styled from "styled-components"

const Tr = styled.tr`
    display: block;
    /* height: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? '100%' : '0px'};
    opacity: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? '1' : '0'};
    visibility: ${props => props.show && props.taskDone ? 'visible' : 'hidden'};
    transition: 0.2s; */
`;

function TaskRow(props) {

    return (<React.Fragment>
        {console.log('render', props.task)}
        <Tr show={props.show} taskDone={props.task.done}>
            <td>
                {props.task.title}
            </td>
            <td>
                {props.task.description}
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="checkbox"
                    checked={props.task.done}
                    onChange={() => props.toggleDoneTask(props.task.id)}
                />

            </td>
        </Tr>
    </React.Fragment>)

}


export default memo(TaskRow, (prev, next) => {
    const prevTaskKeys = Object.keys(prev.task);
    const nextTaskKeys = Object.keys(next.task);
  
    const sameLength = prevTaskKeys.length === nextTaskKeys.length;
    const sameEntries = prevTaskKeys.every(key => {
      return nextTaskKeys.includes(key) && prev.task[key] === next.task[key];
    });
    
    return sameLength && sameEntries;
})
```

I found a solution in another question with  useReduce and setTaskItems as a function , but I don't understand why I have to use it as a function if I am not modifying state multiple times, or anything like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is when `toggleDoneTask` gets memoized. When it gets memoized, its inner referenced state value are also memoized, corresponding to an outdated state value.

Once you click 1, Task 2 and 3 will use the same previous props, where `toggleDoneTask` does not have the current state.

To solve this you need to refactor `toggleDoneTask`. Instead of updating state as `setTaskItems(tasks)` you need to pass a function to your setState like `setTaskItems(prevTasks => { // ... some logic; return nextask})`. Passing a function, `prevTasks` param will be always the correct one.

Given all that, if you refactor `toggleDoneTask` like below everything will work as expected:

```
const toggleDoneTask = (id) => {
    setTaskItems(taskItems => {
        let taskItemsCopy = [...taskItems].map((task) => ({ ...task }))
        let newItems = taskItemsCopy.map((t) => {
            if (t.id === id) {
                t.done = !t.done
            };
            return t;
        })
        localStorage.setItem('tasks', JSON.stringify(newItems))
        return newItems
    })
}
```

Comment: What would be the internal values of the ToggleDoneTask function? taskItemCopy and newItems?

Comment: `taskItems` would be an outdated reference which would cascade to other values. when you pass function to setState, there is no reference passed there. it's a function that will be called pointing to the correct state. actually it's `taskItems` reference that will damage all other variables.

Comment: So every time I use react.memo, will the current useState reference be lost?

Comment: let's say that with memo, when you click on #1, #2 and #3 will look at props and say "Thanks, but since props are the same I will keep with my old component. there is no need to rerender! that old state object inside that function I still have have its reference so I don't need a new one!"

Comment: remember that  state is not mutated in react, it evolves and generates a new one. this way, each update generates a new object with different reference. if a component doesn't rerender it will still have the same reference and not a new one.

Comment: Ohh, now everything is clear, I have been trying to understand this for 3 days, thank you very much!